# Hiding inherited parent case class implementation in scala

Tags: scala

This is a very specific request, so allow me to lay out a hypothetical case before I dive into the code.

Assume you have many rows in a table that are identical -- in order to distinguish one row from another, we would want to **potentially** add a random number column that can help prevent skewing of the data. For example:

```
--------------------------
|         MyClass1       |
--------------------------
| value1 | value2 | skew |
--------------------------
|   4    |   6    | 4962 |
--------------------------
|   4    |   6    | 6510 |
--------------------------
|   500  |   700  | 0    |
--------------------------
|   500  |   700  | 0    |
--------------------------
```

In this case, the skew helps to prevent clumping of data into one location.

One could do the following:

```
case class MyClass1(value1: Int, value2: Int, skew: Int)
```

and instantiation of the skew would be left to the caller, ie:

```
MyClass1(value1 = 4, value2 = 6, skew = ComplexFunc(value1, value2))
```

However, assume I have many classes that need this skew value. In this case, having an implementation for each would be error prone, plus it also requires the caller to know about the skew value. Thus, I want to hide the skew value and its implementation like so:

```
case class SkewClass(skew: Int)
object SkewClass {
    def apply(skewCondition: Boolean) : SkewClass = {
       if (skewCondition) SkewClass(RandomInt()) else SkewClass(0)
    }
}

case class MyClass1 extends SkewClass(
    val value1 : Int = 0
    val value2 : Int = 0
    val skew : Int = this.apply(value1 != 500 && value2 != 700)
}
```

In short, I want to be able to create an instance of MyClass1 with a potentially random integer tacked on at the end called "skew." ie:

```
scala> val x = MyClass1(value1 = 500, value2 = 700)
x: MyClass1 = MyClass1(500, 700, 0)

scala> val y = MyClass1(value1 = 52, value2 = 63)
y: MyClass1 = MyClass1(52, 63, 5347)

scala>
```

Obviously, the code above does not compile (I'm still new to scala), but is there a way to modify this code to allow for this random integer to be tacked on?

Comment: is it working for you with default value for `skew` parameter  `case class MyClass1(value1: Int, value2: Int, skew: Int = RandomInt)` ?

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough. I edited the question to be more explicit

Comment: Can you explain why you want to distinguish between identical rows? There may be other ways of doing this (e.g. a `count` field rather than multiple rows) so it feels like an [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)  question.

Comment: @Tim this case is hypothetical, so don't assume this is exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko has already given the solution to your **tl;dr** question, so it is not clear what more you are looking for.

Comment: @Tim The function RandomInt is just an example -- I want to have a complex function that calculates the value of skew based on other child class parameters, for example:

```MyClass1(value1: Int, value2: Int, skew: Int = ComplexFunc(value1, value2))``` but I also want to be able to do ```MyClass2(value1: Int, value2: Int, value3: Int, skew: Int = ComplexFunc(value1, value2, value2)```

Comment: @Tim I added extra clarification to the question -- it's much more specific now.

Comment: @GeoffreySaunders I doubt that it's possible to implement as you requested because you need `skew` as a native field of case class but you can't extend case class by case class. So it seems that the only way you can hide `skew` field from caller is to implement `apply` method in companion object for each of you new case class because this is the only place where all parameters are available and you can use them to pass to you ComplexFunc.

Comment: Should the `skew` value affect the equality test for the class? If I create `val z = MyClass1(value1 = 52, value2 = 63)`, should `y == z` be `true` or `false` or does it not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a `case class` with fields that are initialised from other fields, but you can use the class object to do it. Start with a function to calculate the skew:

```
def computeSkew(value1: Int, value2: Int) =
  if (value1 == 500 && value2 == 700) 0 else Random.nextInt()
```

Then use the class object to create instances of it:

```
case class MyClass1 private(value1: Int, value2: Int, skew: Int)

object MyClass1 {
  def apply(value1: Int, value2: Int): MyClass1 =
    MyClass1(value1, value2, computeSkew(value1, value2))
}
```

Another option is to add the field by extending a `Skew` class, but objects with the same `value1` and `value2` will always compare as equal because the `skew` will not be included in the `equals` test.

---

As mentioned in the comments, I am not sure that adding `skew` to the core data objects is the right way to deal with the duplication problem. It would be better to wrap the skew round the object when using it in the table and keep the original data untouched.

A simple wrapper would look like this:

```
case class WithSkew[T] private(data: T, skew: Int)

object WithSkew {
  def apply[T](data: T): WithSkew[T] =
    WithSkew(data, Random.nextInt())
}

val x = MyClass1(500, 700)
val xSkew = WithSkew(x)
```

You then use `xSkew` in the table to avoid duplicates, and extract the `data` field when you take rows out of the table again.

---

The previous version does not perform the custom skew calculation based on `value1` and `value2`. This can be addressed by introducing a typeclass to give the skew calculation for a specific class:

```
trait HasSkew[T] {
  def skew(instance: T): Int
}

case class DefaultSkew[T]() extends HasSkew[T] {
  def skew(instance: T): Int = Random.nextInt()
}

object HasSkew {
  implicit object skew1 extends HasSkew[MyClass1] {
    def skew(data: MyClass1): Int =
      computeSkew(data.value1, data.value2)
  }
}

case class WithSkew[T] private(data: T, skew: Int)

object WithSkew {
  def apply[T](data: T)(implicit sk: HasSkew[T] = DefaultSkew[T]()): WithSkew[T] =
    WithSkew(data, sk.skew(data))
}
```

The `WithSkew` wrapper will use the skew calculation in `DefaultSkew` unless there is an implicit instance of `HasSkew` for that class.

This version has more boilerplate code, but it will allow any class to be wrapped with a `skew` value, and allows the skew calculation to be tailored to each specific class if required.

Comment: So, essentially, in the last answer, all the class needs to do is extend WithSkew and, optionally, override the skew function to do some other computation of the skew?

Comment: No, you don't touch the original class at all. You use `WithSkew` to *wrap* the original object before putting it in the table just the same as the second version. The last version just adds the option of creating a custom method to compute the skew for a particular class.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you want all of your structures to share a property, `Skew`, but not necessarily any other details. The best solution is to just use a trait here.

```
trait Skew {
  def skewCondition: Boolean
  lazy val skew: Int = if (skewCondition) RandomInt() else 0
}

case class AlwaysSkew(v1: Int, v2: Int) extends Skew {
  override val skewCondition: Boolean = true
}

case class ConditionalSkew(v1: Int, v2: Int) extends Skew {
  override val skewCondition: Boolean = (v1 != 500) && (v2 != 700)
}

val x = ConditionalSkew(500, 700)
val y = ConditionalSkew(1234,5678)
x.skew //0
y.skew //A random Int
```

Comment: Note that all instances with the same `value1` and `value2` are equal even if the `skew` value is different. There is also an extra `val skewCondition` in every data object which feels unnecessary.

Comment: This answer is very good, but abstracting out the skew is really the goal, and the implementing classes are still very aware of the skew still existing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for here but based on your description this is what I got:

```
class SkewedClass(values: Int*) {
    lazy val skew: Int = {
        values.sum * 1234
    }
}

case class MyClass1(value1: Int, value2: Int) extends SkewedClass(value1, value2)
case class MyClass2(value1: Int, value2: Int, value3: Int) extends SkewedClass(value1, value2, value3)
```

Replace the skew implementation with whatever complex function you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the implementation details of skew you can use self-type of scala.

```
trait SkewTrait {
   def skew: Int
}


// package MyClass1
sealed class SkewClass1(value1: Int, value2: Int) {
this: SkewTrait =>
override def skew: Int = if (value1 == 500 && value2 == 700) 3 else 0
}

case class MyClass1(value1:Int, value2: Int) extends SkewClass1(value1, value2) with SkewTrait


// package MyClass2
sealed class SkewClass2(value1: Int) {
   this: SkewTrait =>
   override def skew: Int = if (value1 == 300) 4 else 0
}

case class MyClass2(value1: Int, value2: Int) extends SkewClass2(value1) with SkewTrait


println(MyClass1(1,2).skew)
println(MyClass2(300,5).skew)
```

result:

```
0
4
```